# Django dynamic menu context processor

Tags: django, django-templates

I am working on a dynamic menu for an ecommerce and I am about to use the context_processor. I want the menu to be displayed in all the templates and this menu can change ( add/remove options ) from admin.

The problem is, when creating the menu in the context_processor, will I be accessing the database everytime I load any page ? it doesn't sound very optimal for a menu. Is there any other approach to consider ? By writing a custom template tag I will be having the same issue.

Comment: If your menu is stored in the db, then yes of course you will be accessing the db every time you query it. Why do you think that is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Potentially yes you will be hitting that database for every page access. I suggest using caching. Django provides some functions for doing caching that you can make use of ([docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/)).

You can do it in the template and instead of a context processor create a [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/).

```
{% load cache %}
{% load menu %}
{% cache 500 menu "unique-options" %}
    {% generate_menu %}
{% endcache %}
```

Where I've put "unique-options" you would include a string that is specific to the version of the menu you're using. So if you have one that is for users that are staff and on for those that are not you could use `request.user.is_staff` to differentiate between the types of menu, otherwise the cache can serve the wrong menu to people.

Alternatively you could do it as part of the function itself, this would work if you're using a context processor or a template tag.

```
from django.core.cache import cache

def generate_menu():
    menu_cache_key = "menu" + differentiating_string
    menu = cache.get(menu_cache_key)
    if menu:
        return menu
    ...steps to generate menu here...
    cache.set(menu_cache_key, menu, 500)
    return menu
```